# how to add our menu item in existing application

Tags: blackberry

i want to make an application in which ,if user is sending sms through default messenger by blackberry,for sending there are certain menuitems appears.
i want to add mymenuitem on that list how could i do that plz help me..
thkz alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly which application you're referring to, but if it's in [ApplicationMenuItemRepository](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/menuitem/ApplicationMenuItemRepository.html) then you can register an [ApplicationMenuItem](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/menuitem/ApplicationMenuItem.html) with it and it will show up in that application's menu.