# how to add our menu item in messenger of blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to add mymenuitem on smssending menulist,

How could I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add our menu item in existing application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421135/how-to-add-our-menu-item-in-existing-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just override the makeMenu method and add whatever you want.

```
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
    menu.add(getExitItem(0,0));    
}

public MenuItem getExitItem(int ordinal, int priority) {
    return new MenuItem("Close", ordinal, priority) {
        public void run() {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };
}
```